# List of replacing methods between gazebo versions

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are a lot over different versions of Gazebo and example code. Unfortunately they cannot easily be used together. Any idea where I can find a list of methods that explains which 'old' methods are replaced by the new ones?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23609/list-of-replacing-methods-between-gazebo-versions/) by [PeterHer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14875/peterher/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

They should all be listed in the [migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Migration.md).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0